# Why do I get a "Name is not defined" error message when calling another function within a class?

Tags: python

Function tword should take the output from listsplit and perform an action on the output. Since I have truncated the code for clarity, the output should be exatly the same as the output if you change the last line to `print(listsplit(text))`, which returns `['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven']` Instead, whenever I run the code, the tword function fails to call the listsplit function. I get an error message: "NameError: name 'wordicts' is not defined".

```
class wordicts:
    def listsplit(text):
        l = text.split(" ")
        return l
    def tword(text):
        l = wordicts.listsplit(text)
        return l

    hw = "One Two Three Four Five Six Seven"
    print(tword(hw))
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're trying to structure your code in this way? What is your objective?

Comment: @DavidBuck, good question to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your methods do not take the `self` parameter as first argument. 
If you don't need a reference to the instance of the class, you should use the `@staticmethod` decorator.

Secondly, your method call is still inside the class body. I don't think that this is on purpose. This is also the reason why the NameError gets raised.
The part `print(wordicts.tword(hw))`gets executed during class definition time, where the class itself does not exist yet.

As you mentioned that in the real code a bit more logic is involved I assume that you have your reasons to keep the methods inside a class.
In this case, you should try the following:

```
class wordicts:
    @staticmethod
    def listsplit(text):
        l = text.split(" ")
        return l

    @staticmethod
    def tword(text):
        l = wordicts.listsplit(text)
        return l

hw = "One Two Three Four Five"
print(wordicts.tword(hw))
```

Comment: This completely defeats the purpose of the class to exist, you might as well just define `listsplit` and `tword` as regular functions... or really, just *one* of these functions are required.  Though this really goes back to *why* OP is structuring their code this way.

Comment: You are right, of course, as long as the class really only contains those two methods. But as OP stated there seems to be a bit more going on in the class and he only truncated the code two narrow down the exact spot where the problem occurs, I will assume that he has his reasons to keep it as a class.

Answer (score 2):

The functions should belong to the class instance, note the use of the `self` argument in first position:

```
class WordDict:
    def listsplit(self, text):
        l = text.split(" ")
        return l
    def tword(self, text):
        l = self.listsplit(text)
        return l

hw = "One Two Three Four Five Six Seven"
wd = WordDict()
print(wd.tword(hw))
```

However, unless you're doing a *lot* more with this class, it seems like overkill and you'd be better served with list comprehension or lambdas etc.